# Clone function resulting in strange event behaviour with datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a task to allow users to blacklist N amount of dates, I am using the clone(true) function when a click event is detected. The date picker only works on the original 'date-holder' - when I click the calendar icon on any cloned divs - it will open the datetime picker for the original div. Any ideas?

The image demonstrates the issue at hand - I had clicked the calendar on the cloned bottom left row - but it opened the original, top left input.

[Image of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5HDB.png)

```
<div class="date-holder">
  From
   <div class="col-sm-6" style="margin-top: 3.5px; margin-bottom: 3.5px;">
      <div class='input-group date datetimepicker'>
          <input type='text' class="form-control"/>
             <span class="input-group-addon">
                 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
             </span>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="date-holder">
    To
   <div class="col-sm-6" style="margin-top: 3.5px; margin-bottom: 3.5px;">
      <div class='input-group date datetimepicker'>
          <input type='text' class="form-control"/>
             <span class="input-group-addon">
                 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
             </span>
     </div>
</div>


$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".datetimepicker").datetimepicker();

    $("#addDate").click(function () {
        $(".date-holder:first").clone(true).insertBefore("#addDateHolder");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`clone(true)` or plain Javascript `cloneNode(true)` only copies the Element and never the Events with it.
So if you make a clone, make sure you add the events to it afterwards.

Check out [cloneNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode)

Answer (score 0):

Destroy and reintialize the datepicker on each click

```
$("#addDate").click(function () {
        $(".datetimepicker").destroy()
        $(".date-holder:first").clone(true).insertBefore("#addDateHolder");
        $(".datetimepicker").datetimepicker();
    });
```

Comment: doesn't work, i've also modified your suggestion as per docs - '$('.datetimepicker').data("DateTimePicker").destroy(); - this doesn't return an error but the same issue/result applies.